# WebApi2 Google OAuth2 middleware error response

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, google-signin

For user authentication with external providers such as Google, it is using specific Owin middlewares. As for example Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google. WebAPI2 template uses this to support implicit flow authentication (response_type=token). But what about Code flow?

Is it possible to implement Code flow (response_type=code)?

After debugging those OAuth providers I noticed that passing return_type=code to Google, it successfully authenticates and returns json with access and refresh tokens, then user gets signed in by api/Account/ExternalLogin endpoint but at the end of the flow I get redirected to 
http://localhost:50321/?error=unsupported_response_type#.

I could not really find the flow where and why it is setting this specific error in the assembly.

Startup.Auth.cs looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        PublicClientId = "self";
        var tokenTimeSpanInHours = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessTokenLifeTimeInHours"];

        OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToInt16(tokenTimeSpanInHours)),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthServerOptions);
        var googleOAuthOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            AccessType = "offline",
            Provider = new CustomGoogleAuthProvider(),
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAccountClientId"].ToString(),
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAccountClientSecret"].ToString()           
        };
        googleOAuthOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
        googleOAuthOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        googleOAuthOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send");
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOAuthOptions);
    }
```

Where is the problem then? Do I need some explicit configuration to tell that I want code flow? Is it supported?

Comment: Pls read https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#server-flow to see if it can help (`response_type, which in a basic request should be code.`)